# Alterar a posição dos textos só em html

Tags: html, css

Eu gostava de fazer algo do género de um media screen no html, gostava que no telemovel o botão para aparecer os filtros aparecerem em baixo da denuncia mas em computador não, como posso fazer isso?

TELEMOVEL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

COMPUTADOR:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo:

```html
<button id="filtroselects">
  <img src="/imagens/iconfiltro.png" height="40px" width="40px"> Filtros
</button>

<div id="escolha">
<form id="selectsfiltro">
    <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
    <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">0-17</option>
        <option value="2">18-25</option>
        <option value="3">26-35</option>
        <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/> 
    <h6>Sexo:</h6>
    <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="5">Masc</option>
        <option value="6">Fem</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
    <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="7">Sim</option>
        <option value="8">Não</option>
    </select>


    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Localidade:</h6>
    <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
        <option ></option>
        <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
        <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
        <option value="11">Bragança</option>
        <option value="12">Braga</option>
        <option value="13">Porto</option>
        <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
        <option value="15">Viseu</option>
        <option value="16">Guarda</option>
        <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
        <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option value="19">Leiria</option>
        <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="21">Santarém</option>
        <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
        <option value="23">Évora</option>
        <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
        <option value="25">Beja</option>
        <option value="26">Faro</option>
        <option value="27">Açores</option>
        <option value="28">Madeira</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>

    <div class="botesdefiltrar">
        <button id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Filtrar</button>
        <button type="reset" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Limpar Filtro</button>
  </div>   
  </div>

  <br>

  <h5 id="denuncia">Caso saiba de algum caso de violencia doméstica
  <a href="https://www.cmjornal.pt/mais-cm/eu-reporter-cm?ref=geral_MenuHeader" class="denunciastyle" target="_blank">denuncie aqui</a>
  </h5>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao meu ver a opção mais simples para isso é usar `display:flex` junto com a propriedade `order` e no `@media` mudar o `order` para colocar os elementos da forma que quiser. No caso eu peguei um `ID` que já tinha no `H5` e coloquei `order: -1` quando a tela for menor que `768px`, assim o `H5` pula para o topo do container.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima. Eu criei um *container flex* englobando todos os outros conteúdos para facilitar, mas se for do seu agrado pode colocar o próprio `body` como sendo o *container flex*

```css
.d-flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #denuncia {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <button id="filtroselects">
    <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" height="40px" width="40px"> Filtros
  </button>

  <div id="escolha">
    <form id="selectsfiltro">
      <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
      <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">0-17</option>
        <option value="2">18-25</option>
        <option value="3">26-35</option>
        <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
      </select>

      <br />
      <br />
      <h6>Sexo:</h6>
      <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="5">Masc</option>
        <option value="6">Fem</option>
      </select>

      <br />
      <br />
      <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
      <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="7">Sim</option>
        <option value="8">Não</option>
      </select>


      <br />
      <br />
      <h6>Localidade:</h6>
      <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
        <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
        <option value="11">Bragança</option>
        <option value="12">Braga</option>
        <option value="13">Porto</option>
        <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
        <option value="15">Viseu</option>
        <option value="16">Guarda</option>
        <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
        <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option value="19">Leiria</option>
        <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="21">Santarém</option>
        <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
        <option value="23">Évora</option>
        <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
        <option value="25">Beja</option>
        <option value="26">Faro</option>
        <option value="27">Açores</option>
        <option value="28">Madeira</option>
      </select>
    </form>

    <br>

    <div class="botesdefiltrar">
      <button id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Filtrar</button>
      <button type="reset" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Limpar Filtro</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <h5 id="denuncia">Caso saiba de algum caso de violencia doméstica
    <a href="https://www.cmjornal.pt/mais-cm/eu-reporter-cm?ref=geral_MenuHeader" class="denunciastyle"
      target="_blank">denuncie aqui</a>
  </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: a sua resposta foi literalmente perfeita! obrigado!

Comment: @DavidMv eu que fico feliz em ter ajudado ;) []´s